# ASP.NET MVC - why ViewBag prop return "value" string instead of actual value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass some flag into a view and get it back. 
But requirements are:

- this flag is not part of model
- and it must not be stored in session or such.

I mean - *flag visibility scope* should be - *current page* for *current user* only.

I tried to put it into a ViewBag like this:

```
    public ActionResult Product_Add()
    {
        ViewBag.IsNew = true;
        ViewData["IsNew"] = ViewBag.IsNew;
        ViewBag.RecordActionName = "Add";
        return View("Product_Edit");
    }
```

And then use this code in *.cshtml:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="IsNew1" value="@ViewBag.IsNew" />
    <input type="hidden" name="IsNew2" value='@ViewData["IsNew"]' />
```

But in resulting HTML I see this:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="IsNew1" value="value" />
    <input type="hidden" name="IsNew2" value='value' />
```

Then I tried this code in *.cshtml:

```
    @{ string isNewRec = ViewBag.IsNew.ToString(); }
    <input type="hidden" name="IsNew1" value="@isNewRec" />
```

And now it works:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="IsNew1" value="True" />
```

Question is - why first attempt put "value" text instead of boolean value into HTML?

Also the strange thing - this code works fine:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ProductID" value="@ViewBag.ProductID" />
```

So, for integer values in *ViewBug* it works, returns an actual interger value, but for boolean it returns "value" text.

Another part of question.
Currently I use code like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Product_Commit(Product pProduct)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AbcProducts ctx = new AbcProducts();
            bool isNew = Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Form["IsNew"]); 
            if (isNew)
                ctx.Products.Add(pProduct);
            else
            { 
              // [...]
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Could you recommend something *more correct from MVC point of view* to pass non-model parameter into a view and get it back then with submited data?
But this parameter should not be stored anywhere where other pages can see it somehow.

Comment: why are you using normal html input tag, user html helper like `@Html.HiddenFor()`

Comment: User Request.Form["IsNew1"] instead of Request.Form["IsNew"].

Comment: Sorry, I do not see - how I can use @Html.HiddenFor here? I tried @Html.HiddenFor(m => ViewTag.IsNew) but it fail with compiler error. Note: about "IsNew" vs. "IsNew1" I know it, that was my intermediate experiments with name, so different name is not a problem.